# Ball not thrown in proper direction in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game where the player throws basketball in 3d view, but it may not throw properly. I need ball thrown properly on the z direction when a player moves their mouse up.

reference link of game what I want:

reference link [1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dumadugames.basketball)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour
{

public static BallController instance;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject Player;

private Vector3 touchStart;

private Vector3 touchEnd;

private Vector3 screenPoint;

private Vector3 offset;

void OnMouseUp ()
{
    ThrowBall ();
}
public void ThrowBall ()
{
        touched = true;
        Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3 ();
        Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 ();
        touchStart.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane - (.2f);
        touchEnd.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane - (0.08f);

        pos1 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touchStart);
        pos2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touchEnd);

        Vector3 v = pos2 - pos1; 
        v.z = 0.02f;

        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (v * 600, ForceMode.Impulse);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the local z axis, with transform.forward:

```
Vector3 v = pos2 - pos1; 
        v.z = 0.02f * transform.forward;
 Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (v * 600, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

or you can use like

```
v.z = 0.02f;
 Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (v * 600 * transform.forward, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: thanks for replay but i do this so occur error like implicitly convert type

Comment: Vector3 v = pos2 - pos1; 
v.z = 0.02 * transform.forward;
Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (v * 800, ForceMode.Impulse);

Comment: I have try both way

Comment: `v.z= 0.02f * transform.forward` is incorrect. `transform.forward` is a vector3, but `v.z` is a float. If you want to throw the ball forward, set v to transform.forward and multiply v, not v.z, by the magnitude you want. if your trying to throw the ball at the angle between pos2 and pos1, set v to pos2 - pos1 and then multiply v by the magnitude you want.